# Multiple plots are not showing up in a single figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

Am using following code to print to plot stock prices and a vertical line on one graph. But of them work individually but i cant plot both on one graph

```
import datetime as dt
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get the data for the stock Apple by specifying the stock ticker, start date, and end date
data = yf.download('AAPL','2020-02-01','2020-02-10', interval='15m')


data.Close.plot(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.axvline(dt.datetime(2020, 2, 2)) ## No effect if previous line is there. 

plt.show()
```

The vertical line is shown only if i comment data.Close.plot(figsize=(10, 5)) line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always good to get the [figure and the axes handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162443/why-do-many-examples-use-fig-ax-plt-subplots-in-matplotlib-pyplot-python) such that subsequent manipulation can be done easily.

```
import datetime as dt
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# added following line to avoid a warning of future support of datetime
# https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18301#issuecomment-344580274
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters

# Get the data for the stock Apple by specifying the stock ticker, start date, and end date
data = yf.download('AAPL','2020-02-01','2020-02-10', interval='15m')
register_matplotlib_converters()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10, 5))
ax.plot(data.Close)
ax.axvline(dt.datetime(2020, 2, 2), color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That worked. How do i show two graphs on same graph with different scales on on right side and one on left? As of now if i do that one graph looks flat horizontal as the value of other graph are too big

Comment: You mean `twinx`? https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/two_scales.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-two-scales-py